# Disqus and iOS integration - UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, disqus

I'm trying to integrate Disqus into my iOS app.
I'm following the very well written guide written by the guys at Disqus here
https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472096

I'm basically using a UIWebView to show a hosted HTML page, which loads the disqus comments
Everything is working fine.

Am able to view comments , add comment as seen here.

Now i select the add image option and i get this menu here.

[image]

Now when i select the 'Photo Library' , the view controller dismisses and throws a warning in the console

> Warning: Attempt to present UIImagePickerController: 0x7faebb247a00
>   on UINavigationController: 0x7faebb179400 whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

Basically the comments view (as seen in screenshot) is shown  Modally from another view controller which was also shown modally.

I was wondering if we cannot show multiple view controllers modally and then the Disqus ImagePicker too is trying to present itself on top of 2 modally presented view controllers.  Is this the issue?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,
KamyFC

Comment: Yes KamyFC we will not be able to show multiple VC modally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed this.

I avoided showing view controllers Modally and i can select images.